# imagemagick font at sign (@) missing

Tags: fonts, imagemagick, photoshop

I am using this font with imagemagick: http://www.fonts2u.com/sixty-four-dollar-question-medium.font in the following command:

```
width=`identify -format %w $1`; \
convert  -fill '#333' -gravity east  -size ${width}x50 \
      -font fonts/SixtyFourDollarQuestion.ttf caption:'email@address.here' \
      $1 +swap -gravity south -composite $1
```

Imagemagick renders a '?' in place of the '@' indicating that it cannot find the @ symbol. But, when I install the same font library onto my machine (mac OS 10.7) I am able to use the font and @ symbol within photoshop.

EDIT:

I'm running the code in a bash script executed directly from the terminal. The encoding of the script is UTF-8. When I change the font the @ sign gets printed without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font does not contain the '@' symbol character (U+0040). This is evident right on the page you linked to. The '@' symbol should appear right before the uppercase 'A', but it's not there. Inspecting the font's glyph repertoire in detail confirms this.

In some cases, text containing an '@' symbol set in this font may use a "fallback" font to show *an* '@' symbol, but that symbol is not coming from the "Sixty Four Dollar Question" font; it's coming from some other font in the system.

If you want an '@' symbol for that font, you should contact the font designer and ask them to add it.

Comment: Photoshop used a similar hand drawn font for the @ sign, I assumed it to be the same. Do you know if it is possible to edit the font file to put in my own @ symbol?

Comment: To answer that, I'd recommend you to check the license terms to see whether edits/changes are allowed (and whether you need to make those edits available), then determine whether you have the skills to run a font editing program to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You do not say how you are running the code but I would check the encoding on the text editor you are using and if running through a webpage the charset.

Comment: I'm running the code in a bash script executed directly from the terminal. The encoding of the script is UTF-8. When I change the font the @ sign gets printed without a problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892693/edit-ttf-font-file-to-add-in-missing-symbol