# edit .ttf font file to add in missing symbol

Tags: fonts, truetype

The following font is missing the @ sign. I would like to create a copy of the font file with my own @ symbol added to it:

http://www.fonts2u.com/sixty-four-dollar-question-medium.font

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Fontforge should be able to do that. http://fontforge.github.io