# modification font in runtime

Tags: android, fonts

is there any way to modify font in runtime for android or combine two font file. I need to add one more character support to a font.

because, if a char does not exist in font file, device show a square for that character.

Comment: refer this link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892693/edit-ttf-font-file-to-add-in-missing-symbol

Comment: I am curious to know why are you considering combining two font files? Do you need to add more than one character later on?

Comment: no I just need add one more char support

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case I think the link Hari provided is your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know what characters are causing you trouble, then you may want to try this :

1. Find position of those characters, let them be i, j, k (and so on) and let N be size of the complete string.
2. Then do something like :

   ```
   String yourString = "Some Text Here"; // this is you string
   Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(yourString);
   // you can also iterate, instead of next few steps
   // typeface1 and typeface2 are your two different font styles
   spannable.setSpan(typeface1, 0, i-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   spannable.setSpan(typeface2, i, i+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   spannable.setSpan(typeface1, i+1, j-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   spannable.setSpan(typeface2, j, j+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   spannable.setSpan(typeface1, j+1, k-1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
   spannable.setSpan(typeface2, k, k+1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); // and so on
   spannable.setSpan(typeface1, k+1, N, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); 
   textview1.setText(spannable); // this is your textview and setting of font
   ```

Or you can create your custome typeface and apply it to the view you want. In that you can apply first font forall characters except for the ones it cant handle. For those, you can apply the second one. I dont know how much feasible is that. I will try it out and let you know.

See if this is of any use.