# Is there a way to join two ttf fonts files glyphs

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, arabic, webfonts

I have an Arabic font called [Qairwan.ttf](http://www.arafonts.com/details.aspx?fontName=QAIRWAN.TTF&ID=2825) -*click the previous link to see its characters map*-. I'd like to convert it into web font. The problem is that any online convertor either regard it as corrupted ot transform it without functionality (i.e it does not change the font face).

I think that it is due to missing Latin Glyphs in its characters map. For example a font named [ae_Cortoba](http://www.arafonts.com/details.aspx?fontName=ae_Cortoba.ttf&ID=867) has full glyphs characters and it works fine in convertors.

So, I ask about any way that allow me edit the first font to add the missing characters to it or even simply fix this problem.

I use fontsquirrel.com

Comment: You might do better to adopt a different font. Google have some early access fonts you might try [here](https://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess)

Comment: @showdev This is not duplicate. The member there asks about merging the same font's subfamilies and of course this is not possible. I ask about adding new different characters.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm not sure what the difference would be -- its still about merging TTF files.

Comment: @showdev It is not only about merging "... or even simply fix this problem." If you noticed the second font character map, you will see the same characters as you see in Arial for Latin characters! i.e the Arabic font author did not has to re design new English characters for example.

Comment: I see what you mean. This might be helpful: [edit .ttf font file to add in missing symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892693/edit-ttf-font-file-to-add-in-missing-symbol)